# UIScrollView + Autolayout: Howto adjust contentsize when removing subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I am struggling with automaticially setting the content size of an `UIScrollView` using `Autolayout`.

The view hierarchy is quite simple:

```
UIView (RootView)
    UIScrollView
        UIView (My own container view)
            UILabel (Headline)
            UILabel (Content)
            UILabel (Headline)
            UILabel (Content)
            ...
            UIButton
```

So the container view hosts a number of `UILabel` pairs, representing a paragraph build up of a headline and some content.

The maximum number is 5 paragraphs, so there are 10 UILabels stacked in the container view. The first (headline) label has a constraint to the top of the container view. All labels are linked with vertical constraints to each other. The last label has a vertical constraint to the `UIButton` the bottom, which itself as a hight and a vertical constraint to the bottom of the container view. Thus the height of the container view is well defined by its subviews.

Additionally to the vertical constraint to the last label, the Button also has a vertical constraint to the first content label (which is the second label) with a lower priority. This constraint is used, when the other labels are removed from the container view (see below).

The container view itself as vertical constraints to the top and bottom of the `UIScrollView`, thus defining the content size.

Depending on the context I set the content of the labels in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"LOC_WebApp", nil);

    if (self.mode == mode1) {
        self.headlineLabel1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);
        self.infoLabel1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);

        self.headlineLabel2.text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);
        self.infoLabel2.text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);

        ...        
    } else {
        self.headlineLabel1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);
        self.infoLabel1.text = NSLocalizedString(@"...", nil);

        [self.headlineLabel2 removeFromSuperview];
        [self.infoLabel2 removeFromSuperview];

        ...
    }

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

In `mode1` (pseudocode) everthing works fine: All labels get their content and the `contentSize` is automatically adjusted. But when removing some labels in the second case, the ScrollView gets the same `contentSize` as in the first case, whigh is too big now. Although the complete content fits on one screen now, one can still scroll down multiple screens to the bottom, just if all labels would still be shown.

Resetting the layout after removing the Labels has no effect.

I found several questions dealing with similar problems. However the solution was to use a singe `UIScrollView` subview and to ensure, that its constraints are setup properly. This is the case here. So what else can I do, to automaticially adjust the `contentSize`?

**Setting the contentSize manually does not work either:**

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height + 30);
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: HI, Andrey! I think there is a better way - to use UITableView instead of UIScrollView, where  UITableViewCells will contain head and info labels.

Comment: Hi Alex! Thank you for you comment. This would be a possible workaround that would (most likely) solve the problem. Hover I would like to stick to the `UIScrollView`, since the example I described is only one scenario where I face this problem. There are other pages/view controllers with different content within the scroll view, that show the same behaviour. This content is not always suitable for a TableView. Thus solving the problem, instead of circumventing it, would be better I think.